# actionbar menu in lower version

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

ActionBar menu is not showing at the top of screen (three dots) if device is having build-in hardware menu button at the bottom.

Actionbar comes properly in my device except menu. How to bring menu at the top right side though i have in build menu at the bottom.

Comment: Post some code. so that we can help u.

Comment: Find this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Actionbar overflow not appearing when hardware navigation button is available.
that time you need to use custom menu button with icon of overflow.